# Dart Flutter - fetching WordPress Custom Post Type using Chopper

Tags: wordpress, flutter, dart, chopper

I am building a mobile with Google Flutter Framework and using Wordpress as the backend for my app.
I want to fetch Wordpress Custom Post Type data in JSON format in Flutter with Chopper Retrofit of Flutter API.

Can anyone help me to build a sample code so I can get started with ease? 
I worked with this ( [Flutter Wordpress](https://github.com/dreamsoftin/flutter_wordpress) ) but I don't know how to use Custom Post Types with this.

https://github.com/dreamsoftin/flutter_wordpress

Or if anyone knows how to use this and fetch custom post types then it would be more easy for me.

Please Help!
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the package you want to use to build a mobile app, there is no example and solution for custom types, (https://github.com/dreamsoftin/flutter_wordpress), but you could fork it, and extend it for specific custom post types. I will show you an example of how to do this (custom fields are excluded):

In ***flutter_wordpress/lib/constants.dart***

add after line #10 
`const URL_POSTS = '$URL_WP_BASE/posts';`

the line for an endpoint for your custom post. Say you have custom post book, you will add an endpoint `books`:

`const URL_BOOKS = '$URL_WP_BASE/books';`

see explanation about this and how to enable REST API for the custom post type here:

https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-rest-api-support-for-custom-content-types/#registering-a-custom-post-type-with-rest-api-support

Then in the ***flutter_wordpress/lib/requests/*** folder, find, clone and rename file:

***params_post_list.dart*** to  ***params_book_list.dart***

And rename here `class ParamsPostList` to class `ParamsBookList`

in folder ***flutter_wordpress/lib/schemas/*** find

***post.dart*** copy and rename to ***book.dart***

And rename here `class Post` to class `Book`

Then in the file ***flutter_wordpress/lib/flutter_wordpress.dart***:

find line `import 'schemas/post.dart';` and after that add line `import 'schemas/book.dart';`

find line  `export 'requests/params_post_list.dart';` and after that add line `export 'requests/params_book_list.dart';`

find line `export 'schemas/post.dart';` and after that add line `export 'schemas/book.dart';`

Then find functions

`async.Future<List<Post>> fetchPosts()`

`Future<Post> _postBuilder()`

`async.Future<Post> createPost({@required Post post})`

copy these functions rename it and replace `Post` with `Book` (case sensitive)

note: find `URL_POSTS` in copied functions and rename to `URL_BOOKS`

Comment: Awesome ...!! Excellent.. Was not expecting this in-brief answer.. Thank you so much. I will add my code here for other people. BTW, can you tell me a hint about custom fields ? I am new in Flutter. And should I use this code or build the same with Chopper library ? Which one is better for WP as back end for android app ?

Comment: You should use this case only if you fork the `flutter_wordpress` project. Let me know if it works :)